# Why no return code from mkdir?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

**OS=Mac OS X.**
**Shell is bash.**

I'm trying to verify the creation of a directory in a shell script.  However, I don't seem to be getting a return code.  Here is the shell code:

```
#!/bin/bash

rv=$(mkdir lib)
echo "The code = $rv !"

if [ "$rv" == "0" ]
then
    echo "created the dir"
else
    echo "no can do, compadre."
fi
```

And the output:

```
mkdir: lib: File exists
The code =  !
no can do, compadre.
```

Whether or not the directory is created, the `else` condition is always true because the `$rv` variable is never "0".  But it doesn't ever seem to be any integer.  Man pages say

```
DIAGNOSTICS
     The mkdir utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
```

Have not been successful with Google searches.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `rv=$(mkdir lib)`, you're capturing `mkdir`'s stdout into `rv`, not its return code. You can access the return code of the last command by reading the `$?` variable, as in

```
mkdir lib
rv=$?
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  I'll mark it the answer when SO let's me (8 minutes to go.)

Comment: As a follow up:  If what I had was capturing stdout, why was `mkdir: lib: File exists` still making it to the console and not being stored in `rv`?

Comment: @MadConan Probably because it was being printed to standard error (stderr), not stdout.

Answer (score 2):

The return code will be `$?`

```
mkdir lib
echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the notation you are using is supposed to work, but what I know is that the command `$?` allows you to retrieve the last return value.

Your code does not work either on my own computer, but this one does:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir lib
rv=$?
echo "The code = $rv !"

if [ "$rv" == "0" ]
then
    echo "created the dir"
else
    echo "no can do, compadre."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your original answer had `rv=$!` which didn't work.  I see you edited it, but Ismail had it right first.

Comment: Indeed, I saw that I was wrong when I tested my code a few seconds after having posted it!